Black screen after install
I just upgraded from 24.04 to 24.10. There were no errors at all, but I'm getting a black screen after login. I can see my cairo-dock, but not my Plasma dock. Right-clicking on the desktop has no effect. KDE apps are not opening, but non-KDE apps work. I can't even open System Settings. I'm running x11 as before. Wayland has issues on my laptop, so I never use it.
This also happened to me when I upgraded to 24.04, but unfortunately I don't remember how I solved it.
UPDATE:
I just created a new user and logged in. Everything is normal.
Any idea what is in my home folder that worked fine with 24.04 but not in 24.10 after the upgade?
UPDATE2:
this is the output of journalctl -xe | grep plasma
Oct 13 09:14:01 iomariLaptop sddm-helper[156068]: Starting X11 session: "" "/etc/sddm/Xsession "/usr/bin/startplasma-x11""                                                                                                      Oct 13 09:14:01 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Reload requested from client PID 156121 ('startplasma-x11')...                                                                                                                      Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-kcminit.service - KDE Config Module Initialization...                                                                                                               Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-kglobalaccel.service - KDE Global Shortcuts Server...                                                                                                               Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop kcminit_startup[156315]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_mouse.so"                                                                               
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop kcminit_startup[156315]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_fonts.so"                                                                               
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop kcminit_startup[156315]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_style.so"                                                                               Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-kcminit.service - KDE Config Module Initialization.                                                                                                                  Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-ksmserver.service - KDE Session Management Server...                                                                                                                Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-kwallet-pam.service - Unlock kwallet from pam credentials.                                                                                                           Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-kded6.service - KDE Daemon 6...                                                                                                                                     
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-kwin_x11.service - KDE Window Manager...                                                                                                                            Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-kglobalaccel.service - KDE Global Shortcuts Server.                                                                                                                  
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop dbus-daemon[156099]: [session uid=1000 pid=156099] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.impl.portal.desktop.kde' unit='plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service' requested by ':1.29' (uid=1000 pid=156293 comm="/usr/libexec/xdg-desktop-portal" label="unconfined")                                                                                                                                                    Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-kded6.service - KDE Daemon 6.                                                                                                                                        
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-kcminit-phase1.service - KDE Configuration Module Initialization (Phase 1)...                                                                                       
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-ksmserver.service - KDE Session Management Server.                                                                                                                   Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-plasmashell.service - KDE Plasma Workspace...                                                                                                                       Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop kcminit_startup[156315]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings_qwidgets/kcm_kgamma.so"                                                                     
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop kded6[156352]: QDBusObjectPath: invalid path "/modules/plasma-session-shortcuts"                                                                                                                     Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop kded6[156352]: kf.dbusaddons: The kded module name "plasma-session-shortcuts" is invalid!                                                                                                            
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop kcminit_startup[156315]: Initializing  "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt6/plugins/plasma/kcms/systemsettings/kcm_touchpad.so"                                                                            Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Finished plasma-kcminit-phase1.service - KDE Configuration Module Initialization (Phase 1).                                                                                         Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop dbus-daemon[156099]: [session uid=1000 pid=156099] Activating via systemd: service name='org.kde.ActivityManager' unit='plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=156352 c
omm="/usr/bin/kded6" label="unconfined")                                                                                                                                                                                          
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service - KActivityManager Activity manager Service...                                                                                            
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop plasmashell[156381]: Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 authentication rejected                                                                      Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop NetworkManager[1356]:   [1728807242.8645] agent-manager: agent[83e538dab67e23fe,:1.291/org.kde.plasma.networkmanagement/1000]: agent registered                                                
Oct 13 09:14:03 iomariLaptop kded6[156352]: QDBusObjectPath: invalid path "/modules/kded_plasma-welcome"                                                                                                                          Oct 13 09:14:03 iomariLaptop kded6[156352]: kf.dbusaddons: The kded module name "kded_plasma-welcome" is invalid!                                                                                                                 
Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-kactivitymanagerd.service - KActivityManager Activity manager Service.                                                                                               Oct 13 09:14:02 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-kwin_x11.service - KDE Window Manager.                                                                                                                               Oct 13 09:14:03 iomariLaptop dbus-daemon[156099]: [session uid=1000 pid=156099] Activating via systemd: service name='org.kde.KScreen' unit='plasma-kscreen.service' requested by ':1.37' (uid=1000 pid=156352 comm="/usr/bin/kded
6" label="unconfined")
Oct 13 09:14:03 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-kscreen.service - KScreen...                                                                                                                                        Oct 13 09:14:03 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-kscreen.service - KScreen.                                                                                                                                           Oct 13 09:14:03 iomariLaptop kernel: plasmashell[156381]: segfault at 7ffed93acf58 ip 00007d04b9a4681a sp 00007ffed93acf10 error 6 in libc.so.6[4681a,7d04b9a28000+196000] likely on CPU 4 (core 2, socket 0)                     Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV                                                                                                        Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.                                                                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Failed to start plasma-plasmashell.service - KDE Plasma Workspace.                                                                                                                  
Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Consumed 959ms CPU time, 141.2M memory peak.                                                                                                            Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Reached target plasma-core.target - KDE Plasma Workspace Core.                                                                                                                      Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-gmenudbusmenuproxy.service - Proxies GTK DBus menus to a Plasma readable format.                                                                                     Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-polkit-agent.service - KDE PolicyKit Authentication Agent...                                                                                                        Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-powerdevil.service - Powerdevil...                                                                                                                                  
Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service - Xdg Desktop Portal For KDE...                                                                                                      Oct 13 09:14:04 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-xembedsniproxy.service - Handle legacy xembed system tray icons.                                                                                                     
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-polkit-agent.service - KDE PolicyKit Authentication Agent.                                                                                                           Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 1.                                                                                                         Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-plasmashell.service - KDE Plasma Workspace...                                                                                                                       
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-xdg-desktop-portal-kde.service - Xdg Desktop Portal For KDE.                                                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started plasma-powerdevil.service - Powerdevil.                                                                                                                                     Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Reached target plasma-workspace.target - KDE Plasma Workspace.                                                                                                                      Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Reached target plasma-workspace-x11.target.                                                                                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop plasmashell[156559]: Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 authentication rejected                                                                      Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting app-org.kde.plasma\x2dfallback\x2dsession\x2drestore@autostart.service - Plasma Session Restore...                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting app-org.kde.plasma\x2dwelcome@autostart.service - Welcome Center...                                                                                                        Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-ksplash-ready.service - KSplash "ready" Stage...                                                                                                                    Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-restoresession.service - KDE Session Restoration...                                                                                                                 
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Finished plasma-restoresession.service - KDE Session Restoration.                                                                                                                   
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Started app-org.kde.plasma\x2dfallback\x2dsession\x2drestore@autostart.service - Plasma Session Restore.                                                                            
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: app-org.kde.plasma\x2dwelcome@autostart.service: Skipped due to 'exec-condition'.                                                                                                   Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Condition check resulted in app-org.kde.plasma\x2dwelcome@autostart.service - Welcome Center being skipped.                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:05 iomariLaptop plasma-fallback-session-restore[156691]: Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 authentication rejected                                                  Oct 13 09:14:07 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV                                                                                                        
Oct 13 09:14:07 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.                                                                                                                         Oct 13 09:14:07 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Failed to start plasma-plasmashell.service - KDE Plasma Workspace.                                                                                                                  Oct 13 09:14:07 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Consumed 1.158s CPU time, 141.4M memory peak.                                                                                                           
Oct 13 09:14:07 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 2.                                                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:07 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Starting plasma-plasmashell.service - KDE Plasma Workspace...                                                                                                                       
Oct 13 09:14:07 iomariLaptop plasmashell[158445]: Qt: Session management error: Authentication Rejected, reason : MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 authentication rejected                                                                      Oct 13 09:14:08 iomariLaptop kernel: plasmashell[158445]: segfault at 7ffc806f2e08 ip 00007b6a5104681a sp 00007ffc806f2dc0 error 6 in libc.so.6[4681a,7b6a51028000+196000] likely on CPU 2 (core 1, socket 0)                     
Oct 13 09:14:09 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=11/SEGV                                                                                                        
Oct 13 09:14:09 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.                                                                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:09 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Failed to start plasma-plasmashell.service - KDE Plasma Workspace.                                                                                                                  
Oct 13 09:14:09 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Consumed 869ms CPU time, 141.7M memory peak.                                                                                                            
Oct 13 09:14:09 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 3.                                                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:09 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Start request repeated too quickly.                                                                                                                     
Oct 13 09:14:09 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: plasma-plasmashell.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.                                                                                                                         
Oct 13 09:14:09 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Failed to start plasma-plasmashell.service - KDE Plasma Workspace.                                                                                                                  
Oct 13 09:14:55 iomariLaptop systemd[156071]: Finished plasma-ksplash-ready.service - KSplash "ready" Stage.                                                                                                                      
Oct 13 09:15:04 iomariLaptop org.freedesktop.Notifications[156524]: org.kde.plasma.waitforname: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout                                                                            Oct 13 09:15:05 iomariLaptop org.kde.KSplash[156697]: org.kde.plasma.waitforname: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout                                                                                          
Oct 13 09:16:55 iomariLaptop org.freedesktop.Notifications[166157]: org.kde.plasma.waitforname: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout                                                                            
Oct 13 09:17:55 iomariLaptop org.freedesktop.Notifications[170977]: org.kde.plasma.waitforname: WaitForName: Service was not registered within timeout

Solved: In case anyone else out there has the same issue, I had to delete " rm -fvr ~/.local/share/plasma*" then logout/login and all was good.
